# On the universal property of the completion of an ordered field

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ordered-fields

I have been trying to write up some notes on completion of ordered fields, ideally in the general case (i.e., not just completing $\mathbb{Q}$ to get $\mathbb{R}$ but considering the completion via Cauchy sequences of any ordered field).  I have found the technical details of this to be surprisingly thorny, especially compared to the relatively clean construction of the completion of a metric space (which takes $\mathbb{R}$ as given).

Finally I found a clean, concise treatment of the general case in $\S$ 8.7 of P.M. Cohn's text *Basic Algebra: Groups, Rings and Fields*.  He does the general case and also includes the universal property of completion.  Following his terminology, let's say an ordered field is **complete** if every Cauchy sequence in that field is convergent (I would say "sequentially complete" to differentiate both from Dedekind completeness and also the possibility of considering more general Cauchy nets).

> Theorem 8.7.1: Let $K$ be an ordered field.  Then there is a complete ordered field $\tilde{K}$ and a dense order-embedding $\lambda: K \rightarrow \tilde{K}$ such that to each order-embedding $f: K \hookrightarrow L$ into a complete ordered field $L$ there is a unique order-embedding $f': \tilde{K} \rightarrow L$ such that $f = f' \circ \lambda$.

I am happy with the existence of $\lambda$.  However, Cohn's proof of the universal property says:

> "Finally, let $f: K \hookrightarrow L$ be an order-embedding in a complete field $L$.  Any element $\alpha$ of $\tilde{K}$ is obtained as the limit of a Cauchy sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $K$; it is easily seen that $\{f(a_n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L$ and so has a limit..."

This sounds reasonable at first glance...but it's false, I think.  Suppose $K = \mathbb{Q}$ and $L = \mathbb{R}((t))$, the latter given the unique ordering in which $t$ is positive and smaller than every positive real number.  It is well-known that $L$ is complete (all I'm using about $L$ is that it is complete and non-Archimedean, and such fields certainly exist, so if you prefer just take any such $L$).  Let $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, so of course $f(a_n) = \frac{1}{n}$.  But we have a problem: the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ is not in fact Cauchy (or equivalently, convergent) in $L$ *because* $L$ is non-Archimedean: the open interval $(-t,t)$ about $0$ contains no terms of the sequence!

[In fact one can make the problem even less subtle.  It is known that ultraproducts and such construct ordered fields which have uncountable cofinality (equivalently, are not first countable in the order topology).  In such a field, the only Cauchy sequences are the eventually constant ones.  In particular such fields are automatically complete. However, such a field contains subfields like $\mathbb{Q}$ which have plenty of not eventually constant convergent sequences.  Clearly an order embedding cannot make a not-eventually-constant sequence eventually constant!]

Thus I claim the distressing fact that a homomorphism of ordered fields need not be even sequentially continuous with respect to the given order topologies: *a fortiori* it need not be continuous.

So the question is: am I making some silly mistake here?  (Cohn is a gold-standard algebraist and his book is lovely and authoritative, even compared to many of the more familiar standard texts.)  If not, is the result even true?  I think it isn't: instead of $\mathbb{R}((t))$ we could take $\mathbb{Q}((t))$ which I believe is still complete -- a sequence is Cauchy iff for each $n$ the sequence of $n$th Laurent series coefficients is eventually constant; hence Cauchy sequences are convergent -- and then the embedding from $\mathbb{Q}$ will not extend to $\mathbb{R}$.  If the result is false, I wonder:

> What is the appropriate universal property of the completion of an ordered field?  (Note that I asked a [similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11622/) about metric spaces here a while back.)  We could require for instance the maps to be "sequentially Cauchy" (i.e., to preserve Cauchy sequences) and then the proof goes through.  But that seems a little weak...

**Added**: One fix is to impose the condition that $f$ too be a dense embedding (i.e., such that in between any two distinct elements of $L$ lies an element of the image of $f$).  This condition is sufficient for Cauchy sequences to map to Cauchy sequences (I think it is not necessary: imagine embedding a field of uncountable cofinality into another field of bigger cofinality).  If we put this in then essentially we get a rather wordy way of saying that the completion is unique, but that is indeed the main application of this result anyway, so far as I know.

---

**Further Added**: The following recent note seems to face some issues on the topology of ordered fields more head-on than what I've seen otherwise in the literature.  Here is the MathSciNet review:

> Tanaka, Yoshio *Topology on ordered fields*. Comment. Math. Univ. Carolin. 53 (2012), no. 1, 139–147. An ordered field is a field $(K,+,∗)$ equipped with a linear order $<$ and the open interval topology $λ(<)$ where the algebra and order are related as follows: if $a,b,c \in K$ and $a<b$, then $a+c<b+c$; and if $c>0$ then $a∗c<b∗c$. Consequently, any ordered field contains an algebraic copy of $\mathbb{Q}$, the usual field of rational numbers. A key issue in this paper is that for a subset $A \subset K$, the topology $λ(<)|A$ that $A$ inherits as a subspace of $(K,λ(<))$ might, or might not, be the same as the open interval topology defined on $A$ by the restricted order $<|A$. The author discusses the Archimedean property of an ordered field, showing, for example, that K is Archimedean if and only if Q is dense in K, and that for any ordered field K, either Q is dense in K or is closed discrete in K. Other results concern Dedekind completeness of K and another result shows that if K is an Archimedean ordered field and if f:K→K′ is a surjective algebraic homomorphism, then the following are equivalent: f is continuous; f is a homeomorphism; and f is order preserving. The paper ends with examples of various ordered fields and homomorphisms.

I haven't been able to get my hands on a copy, but if someone can and it seems relevant, I'd take it as a favor if they'd let me know.

Comment: At the end of the quotation of Cohn's theorem 8.7.1, should "$f = \lambda \circ f'$" instead be "$f = f'\circ\lambda$"?

Comment: @Pete: Is it true when $L$ is Archimedean? For example Dedekind-complete ordered fields are Archimedean.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, that's a special case of my suggested fix, because Q is order-dense in K iff K is Archimedean.  It follows that every homomorphism into an Archimedean field is order-dense.

Comment: Is there a reason why Cohn only considers sequences?

Comment: @Francois: Well, the title of the section is "The Field of Real Numbers", and the chapter goes on to discuss quadratic forms over fields, formally real and otherwise.  Neither nets nor filters appear anywhere in the text, so far as I can see.  I think he's really trying to go one up on the standard (and kind of boring) construction of $\mathbb{R}$ (as am I in my notes)...and I'm catching him out as going a little too far.

Comment: Thanks @Pete! I had to remove part of my answer (or else add a million explanations) because of a technical point. I guess I won't resolve the technicality by reading the book. (Though I might find something else that's interesting!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The statement can be corrected by adding one word:

> Theorem 8.7.1: Let $K$ be an ordered field. Then there is a complete ordered field $\tilde{K}$ and a dense order-embedding $\lambda:K \to \tilde{K}$ such that to each **cofinal** order-embedding $f:K \to L$ into a complete ordered field $L$ there is a unique order-embedding $f′:\tilde{K} \to L$ such that $f=f′\circ \lambda$.

Note that there are only two possibilities for a subfield $K$ of an ordered field $L$: either $K$ is cofinal in $L$ or $K$ is discrete in $L$. [If $K \cap (0,\varepsilon) = \varnothing$ then $K \cap (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon) = \{x\}$ for each $x \in K$.] Similarly an embedding $f:K \to L$  is either cofinal (and uniformly continuous) or discrete (and wildly discontinuous).

There cannot be a theorem that allows discrete embeddings $f:K \to L$. The reason is that every ordered field $K$ is discretely embeddable into the complete ordered field $K((T))$, where $T$ is infinitesimal with respect to $K$, and then there is no copy of $\tilde{K}$ in $K((T))$ in which $K$ is cofinal unless $K$ is already complete.

*Remark 1*: A discrete embedding $f:K \to L$ can never be "sequentially Cauchy" unless all Cauchy sequences in $K$ are eventually constant. In the case where $K$ doesn't have nontrivial Cauchy sequences, then all embeddings are sequentially Cauchy but such a $K$ is also trivially complete. Therefore the theorem with "cofinal" and "sequentially Cauchy" are precisely equivalent.

*Remark 2*: Cohn's completion is unusual because he only considers Cauchy *sequences*. However, it does coincide with the usual topological completion when the ordered field is metrizable. An ordered field is metrizable precisely if it has countable cofinality. When a field has uncountable cofinality, all Cauchy sequences are eventually constant and Cohn's completion trivializes.

Comment: Yes, I said that in my answer.  Do we regard that as the optimal fix? E.g. the density condition is sufficient but not necessary for the map to extend.

Comment: @Pete: Hm... I should have read to the end! I added a more explanation that suggests that nothing more can be done.

Comment: As I said in my question, if you include such a strong hypothesis as "density", you are essentially just asserting the uniqueness of the completion, and phrasing in terms of a universal property seems a little highfalutin.  But are you of the opinion that this is what Cohn (possibly) intended?

Comment: @Pete: It's the natural generalization of "$\mathbb{R}$ is the maximal archimedean ordered field."

Comment: It's *a* generalization, sure, and it seems pretty natural.  But it doesn't feel like a nontrivial example of a universal mapping property.  Given that the completion of a metric space has a *bona fide* universal mapping property which is stronger than just the analogous uniqueness statement, are you so sure that there is no stronger analogue here?  Why?

Comment: But in some sense the assertion that the universal mapping property holds for Cauchy-continuous $f$ is a stronger statement, once we remark that if $f$ is dense then it is Cauchy-continuous.  So I see what you are getting at but I don't (yet) find it completely persuasive: there's more structure here than just the topology.  Couldn't there be a nontrivial necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of $f'$?

Comment: @Pete: Is the last edit convincing?

Comment: OK, I like your current edit, since now you have shown that in fact the asserted result cannot hold for any $K$ (and all $L$) except in the trivial case $K = \tilde{K}$.  (Clearly I had all the ingredients necessary to see this, but I admit that I didn't see it until you told it to me, so thanks!) Still though it does not necessarily seem like the end of the story: unless $K$ is complete we can't allow *all* $f'$, and we *can* allow dense $f'$.  Maybe we can say exactly what can and can't be allowed?

Comment: I think that's it, @Pete. Intuitively: discrete embeddings are wildly discontinuous so you can't expect much from them. Since discrete vs dense is a perfect dichotomy, there is only one maximal result.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  It's hard for me to accept an answer that says "Basically you already knew everything that could be said in this situation." so I'll sit on this for a while and see if anyone else has anything to say...but you may well be right.

Comment: I agree, @Pete. My answer was way more entertaining for me before I read the second half of your question. I was just very excited to have the opportunity to answer one of your questions again!

Comment: Tonight I had a chance to think more about the dichotomy you mention in your answer: if $K$ is a subfield of the ordered field $L$, then $K$ is either discrete or dense.  I had trouble showing this, and eventually I came up with what looks like a counterexample: $\mathbb{R}((t^2)) \subset \mathbb{R}((t))$.  (Your brief argument starts by assuming that $K$ is not cofinal in $L$, but if I am not mistaken, this is stronger than "not dense".  In my example, $K$ satisfies your condition, but $(t,2t) \cap K = \varnothing$.)  What do you think about this?

Comment: Right, @Pete. I changed dense to cofinal.

Answer (score 10):

Sine Emil seems to be rather busy, here is an outline of the Dedekind-style approach to completing an ordered field.

---

$\newcommand{\cut}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}$A *good cut* in $K$ is a pair $\cut{L,R}$ such that:

1. $L$ is a nonempty initial part of $K$ with no maximal element.
2. $R$ is a nonempty final part of $K$ with no minimal element.
3. $L$ and $R$ do not overlap.
4. For every $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there are $x \in L$, $y \in R$ such that $y - x \lt \varepsilon$.

The only new requirement is the last one. When $K$ is Archimedean this is equivalent to saying that $L \cup R$ omits at most one point of $K$. However, when $K$ is not Archimedean, there are some cuts that are not good, such as the cut with lower part $(-\infty,1)\cup(-\infty,2)\cup\cdots$

The field operations for good cuts are defined as usual.

**Fact.** *If $\cut{L_1,R_1}$ and $\cut{L_2,R_2}$ are good cuts then so is $$\cut{L_1,R_1} + \cut{L_2,R_2} = \cut{L_1 + L_2,R_1 + R_2}.$$*

It's not difficult to check that the good cut $\cut{(-\infty,0),(0,+\infty)}$ is an identity for addition of good cuts. Additive inverses also exist:

**Fact.** *If $\cut{L,R}$ is a good cut then so is $\cut{-R,-L}.$ Moreover, $$\cut{L,R}+\cut{-R,-L} = \cut{(-\infty,0),(0,+\infty)}.$$*

Note that the additional requirement comes in handy here since it is equivalent to $R - L = (0,+\infty)$ (modulo the other three requirements).

To understand multiplication of cuts, it helps to think how intervals multiply.
The product $[x_1, y_1] \cdot [x_2, y_2]$ has to be an interval and its endpoints must be among the four products $x_1x_2, x_1y_2, y_1x_2, y_1y_2.$ Since it must contain all four products, the result is $$[\min(x_1x_2, x_1y_2, y_1x_2, y_1y_2),\max(x_1x_2, x_1y_2, y_1x_2, y_1y_2)].$$

**Fact.** *If $\cut{L_1,R_1}$ and $\cut{L_2,R_2}$ are good cuts then so is $\cut{L_1,R_1}\cdot\cut{L_2,R_2} = \cut{L,R}$, where $$\begin{aligned}
L &= \{\min(x_1x_2, x_1y_2, y_1x_2, y_1y_2) : x_1 \in L_1, y_1 \in R_1, x_2 \in L_2, y_2 \in R_2\}, \\
R &= \{\max(x_1x_2, x_1y_2, y_1x_2, y_1y_2) : x_1 \in L_1, y_1 \in R_1, x_2 \in L_2, y_2 \in R_2\}.
\end{aligned}$$*

(The verification that this product is a good cut is actually straightforward arguably less tedious than that with the more common definition by cases.)

It's not difficult to check that the good cut $\cut{(-\infty,1),(1,+\infty)}$ is an identity for multiplication of good cuts. Multiplicative inverses also exist for positive good cuts:

**Fact.** *If $\cut{L,R}$ is a good cut and $0 \in L$ then $\cut{L^{-1},R^{-1}}$ is also a good cut where $$\begin{aligned}
L^{-1} &= (-\infty,0] \cup \{y^{-1} : y \in R\}, \\
R^{-1} &= \{x^{-1} : x \in L \cap (0,+\infty)\}.
\end{aligned}$$
Moreover, $\cut{L,R}\cdot\cut{L^{-1},R^{-1}} = \cut{(-\infty,1),(1,\infty)}.$*

As expected, this last fact is the most tedious of all four to verify due to the fact that $x^{-1}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,+\infty)$. Multiplicative inverses for good cuts $\cut{L,R}$ with $0 \in R$ can be defined similarly or by taking the negative of the inverse of $\cut{-R,-L}.$

After verifying that the operations behave as required, we obtain the following.

**Embedding Theorem.** *If $K$ is an ordered field then the set of all good cuts of $K$ forms an ordered field $\overline{K}$ in such a way that $$x \in K \mapsto \cut{(-\infty,x),(x,+\infty)} \in \overline{K}$$ is a dense emebedding of $K$ into $\overline{K}.$ Furthermore, $\overline{K}$ is complete in the sense that every good cut in $\overline{K}$ is filled.*

The completion $\overline{K}$ has two universal properties:

**Universal Properties.** *Suppose $K$ is an ordered field and $h:K \to \overline{K}$ is the embedding into its field of good cuts.*

1. *If $f:K \to L$ is a dense embedding then there is a unique embedding $g:L \to \overline{K}$ such that $h = g \circ f$.*
2. *If $f:K \to M$ is a cofinal embedding and $M$ is complete then there is a unique embedding $g:\overline{K} \to M$ such that $f = g \circ h$.*

Comment: Please, give the reference to text with construction and results that your mention

Answer (score 6):

I wrote up the material on sequential completion of an ordered field. It appears in Chapter 16 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf).  My perspective was that of Francois Dorais's answer: namely, the correction of Cohn's Theorem with the cofinality hypothesis added to the homomorphism $f: K \rightarrow L$.  I also included the following results:

Let $f: F \rightarrow F'$ be a homomorphism of ordered fields.

> Proposition: Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $F$.  If $\{f(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy, then so is $\{x_n\}$.

$ $

> Proposition (Dorais Dichotomy): Exactly one of the following holds:
> (i) $f(F)$ is discrete in $F'$.
> (ii) $f(F)$ is cofinal in $F'$.

$ $

> Theorem: The following are equivalent:
> (i) $f$ is uniformly continuous.  [Thus $f$ preserves Cauchy sequences.]
> (ii) $f$ is continuous.
> (iii) $f$ is continuous at $0$.
> (iv) $f(F)$ is cofinal in $F'$.

Has anyone seen these results in the extant literature?  I would be interested to know.

Ideally I would like to also give the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ using Dedekind cuts.  But from what I know about Dedekind completion, it can be performed on any linearly ordered set and yields a Dedekind complete linearly ordered set.  But if you want the Dedekind completion of an ordered commutative group $G$ to retain the structure of a commutative group, it is necessary and sufficient for $G$ to be Archimedean.  This makes the prospect of Dedekind completion of an ordered field look more limited.  However, the comments to Niels Diepeveen's answer suggest that it should be possible to find the sequential completion as a subset of the Dedekind completion in a natural way.  Again, I would be very interested to see that in more detail.

(**Added**: I just learned that the construction Emil and Francois are describing is from a [1970 paper of R. Baer](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/en/dms/loader/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0188&DMDID=DMDLOG_0048&LOGID=LOG_0048&PHYSID=PHYS_0181).  I wish I could read German!)

Comment: As Emil explained, the Dedekind-style completion does not use all cuts, only cuts where the left part $L$ and the right part $R$ get arbitrarily close in the sense that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there are $x \in L$, $y \in R$ with $y-x < \varepsilon$. (This requirement is always true in the archimedean case.) So you don't get a field which is complete in the purely order-theoretic sense but it is complete with respect to the uniform topology.

Comment: @François: OK, thanks: this is starting to sink in.  Is it as straightforward to show that you get a complete ordered field from this construction as it is in the Archimedean case (which still has some annoying details to check, IIRC)?

Comment: The equivalence of (i), (ii), and (iii) is essentially proposition 1 in http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/topological+group

Comment: @Niels: sure, that part is very standard. (i) $\implies$ (ii) $\implies$ (iii) is immediate, and (iii) $\implies$ (i) is essentially: "If $x$ is close to $y$, then $x-y$ is close to $0$."  (Although in fact the proof of (iii) $\iff$ (iv) is also immediate!  I count that as a point in favor of the Theorem.)

Comment: Where might I find Baer's paper? (I do read German)

Comment: @Niels: I added a link to the paper.

Comment: For the part I think you are interested in, the actual construction, that paper refers back to a much older paper "Zur Topologie der Gruppen". The 1970 paper essentially tells the reader to "construct the field from proper Dedekind cuts in the usual fashion" and then goes on to prove some properties.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** This answer has been made redundant by the latest version of the
other answer. I am leaving it in place only 
to save the discussions attached to it.

---

You seem to have fully answered almost all of your questions. All I can do
is try to offer a perspective that makes your findings seem more natural.

The Cauchy completion of an ordered field is fundamentally nothing but
the completion of a Hausdorff topological group (the additive group with the order
topology) that "happens to" admit the extension of some extra structure
(multiplication and order). For completions of Hausdorff topological groups we
have the simple universal property

> Every continuous homomorphism of a group into a complete group has a unique 
>   continuous extension to a homomorphism of  its completion.

This property carries over nicely to ordered fields. 
 <del>It "just happens", as
a consequence of the extra structure, that the image of a continuous homomorphism of ordered fields is dense.</del>

---

**Edit:** In the light of some of the comments I should explain that it does
not make a significant difference to the above whether "Cauchy completion" is
interpreted in terms of sequences or filters. If an ordered field is first
countable, then the two are the same; if it isn't, then the sequential completion equals the original field and the universal property applies trivially.

---

**Edit:** I wrote earlier that the image of a continuous homomorphism of ordered fields is dense. Looking again at my reasoning I found I could
only prove that it is cofinal. In fact there seems to be a continuous
endomorphism of $R((x))$ that maps $x$ to $x^2$ and has a nowhere dense
image.  This suggests that it may be hard to state a universal property
in order-theoretic terms.

Comment: That's true but Cohn's "completion" is not the usual topological completion. For example, every field of uncountable cofinality is "complete" in Cohn's sense since every Cauchy *sequence* is eventually constant.

Comment: On the other hand, Cohn's completion is the usual one for metrizable fields and these are precisely the ones with countable cofinality...

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: That’s very true. What puzzles me is why would one ever want to use the Cauchy completion in the first place. The topological completion seems much more natural.

Comment: @Emil: As Pete explained, Cohn's book is targeted at an audience which is perhaps lacking in topological sophistication.

Comment: @François: Still, that does not make it a good idea. I’d also think it does not require *that* much sophistication to index sequences by the cofinality of the field instead of $\omega$. I sincerely hope Pete will not follow Cohn in this case.

Comment: @Emil: I completely agree (though I haven't read the book). It's strange that it happens to work out rather cleanly in the end, though the choice is still terribly confusing for readers that do have topological sophistication.

Comment: Hey guys: yes, I agree with you that from a sufficiently topologically erudite perspective, it is weird to use sequences even when the underlying topological space is not **sequential**.  Notice that I have subtly tipped my hat to this by saying "sequential completion" instead of "Cauchy completion": the latter should yield a complete uniform space, not just a space in which Cauchy sequences converge.

Comment: In terms of what I'll do in my notes...well, actually the notes in which this material currently resides are my *honors calculus* notes, so the motivation for them is really the same as Cohn's: touch up the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ via Cauchy sequences to see what it yields in more generality.  It would really be ridiculous to talk about nets and/or filters in this set of notes (they are supposed to be for very bright, but mathematically mortal, college freshmen).

Comment: However one might argue that a detailed construction of the sequential completion of an ordered field is already ridiculous for an audience of college freshman: I taught the course two years ago and I most certainly did not cover this material in class.  It is likely that this material may also make it into my field theory notes (which already have a good bit of material on ordered fields, and in which I will not hesitate to use filters/nets if I know how to do so and it seems to help).

Comment: @Niels: Thanks for your answer.  I agree with what you say (and even though you are dealing with a slightly more general completion process in general, I agree with you that it would be more natural to consider the more general case).  I also hadn't yet noticed a that a homomorphism of ordered fields is continuous for the order topology if and only if it is dense (I knew only the "if" part).  That's a nice result.

Comment: @Niels: regarding your edit: sure, this is in our note so I know it!  What is surprising/disappointing to me is that a homomorphism of ordered fields is not necessarily continuous for the order topologies (and indeed it is looking like such continuity is rather rare).  This is a feature that (this) one would not have predicted from looking at the Archimedean case.

Comment: Note that you don’t need nets and filters, transfinite sequences are enough. In fact, one does not need any sequences at all, completeness and completions can be described in terms of Dedekind cuts (which in this case are partitions of $K$ into a pair of sets $A<B$ such that for every positive $\epsilon\in K$, there is $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ with $b-a<\epsilon$). The point is that the Cauchy completion satisfies the wrong universal property: since we are talking ordered fields, one should care about the order, not about topology (whether sequential or the usual one). ...

Comment: The purely order-theoretic concepts are that $K$ is a dense subfield of $L$ if there is an element of $K$ between any pair of elements of $L$, $K$ is complete if it has no proper ordered extension where it is dense (or equivalently, if every cut as above can be separated by an element of $K$), and a completion is a (unique) complete extension of $K$ where $K$ is dense (i.e., it safisfies Thm. 8.7.1 for the proper reading of “dense” and “complete”). This coincides with the usual topological completeness and completion, but not with the Cauchy sequential completeness.

Comment: @Emil: Your last two comments contain some interesting ideas.  I would be grateful if you could leave an answer which develops them in more detail.  As a brief response: yes, I am aware that "ordinal-indexed sequences" would suffice over more general nets; whether that is a simplification depends on your perspective.

Comment: About Dedekind cuts: I certainly would have thought that the Dedekind completion is giving you something else in the non-Archimedean case, in particular something which is not compatible with the group structure.  You seem to be suggesting though a modification of the Dedekind-MacNeille completion.  If you can actually construct some kind of larger ordered field that way, I would very much like to hear more about that!

Comment: OK, I’m rather busy now, but I’ll see if I can make it an answer later. Note that once you already *have* the topological completion, it is easy to see that it can be described by cuts: on the one hand, each $a\in\tilde K$ determines the cut $(A_a,B_a)=((-\infty,a]\cap K,(a,+\infty)\cap K)$, $A_a\subsetneq A_b$ for $a<b$ due to density of $K$ in $\tilde K$, and $A_a$ and $B_a$ come arbitrarily close together for the same reason. On the other hand, each such cut $(A,B)$ determines a Cauchy net (due to the extra condition), whose limit $a\in\tilde K$ satisfies $A\le a\le B$.

Comment: @Emil: OK, I can see that you need to look within the Dedekind completion to get what you want in the non-Archimedean case.  Again, I'd be happy to hear more about that...if/when you can spare the time.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I think what Emil is getting at is a more technical version of what I wrote to you last year about the distinction between "pores" and "proper gaps". I would love to see a full account of that.

Comment: As an afterthought to my latest edit: is it at all possible that a cofinal image of a homomorphism is already *sufficient* for continuity?

Comment: @Niels: Yes, cofinality is precisely equivalent to (uniform) continuity for ordered field embeddings. In fact, cofinality is almost literally the same as continuity at $0$.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: That's just beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: (I agree with Francois's comment about cofinality and uniform continuity.  FWIW, I had a part in this via my comment to his answer.)  Thanks, guys: I think this turned out to be an interesting question after all!  I wouldn't mind writing up what we've learned at some point...

Comment: @Pete L.Clark: It would have made my day much easier if I had seen your comment. You even already had the same counterexample!

Answer (score 3):

François G. Dorais has already described in detail the construction of completion using cuts, but let me add another perspective that might look more algebraically-minded.

The following are equivalent for any ordered field $K$:

1. $K$ has no proper ordered extension $L$ in which it is dense (in the sense that there is an element of $K$ between any pair of elements of $L$).
2. Every good cut in $K$ is filled.

For $2\to1$, it suffices to observe that any $a\in L$ determines a good cut $\langle(-\infty,a)\cap K,(a,+\infty)\cap K\rangle$ (condition 4 holds because of density of $K$ in $L$), and the only element of $L$ that can fill it is $a$ itself (again due to density). Thus, $a\in K$.

For $1\to2$, Let $\langle A,B\rangle$ be a good cut that is not filled in $K$. For every polynomial $f\in K[x]$, exactly one of the following must happen (using the fact that a polynomial can change sign only finitely many times in an ordered field):

(+) There are $a\in A$, $b\in B$, and $0<\epsilon\in K$ such that $f(u)>\epsilon$ for every $u\in(a,b)$.

(−) There are $a\in A$, $b\in B$, and $0<\epsilon\in K$ such that $f(u)>-\epsilon$ for every $u\in(a,b)$.

(0) For every $0<\epsilon\in K$, there are $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $-\epsilon<f(u)<\epsilon$ for every $u\in(a,b)$.

The set $I$ of all polynomials satisfying (0) is a prime ideal, and taking (+) as the positive cone induces an ordering on $K[x]/I$, which canonically extends to its fraction field $L$. Then $L$ is an extension of $K$ where $x+I$ fills the cut $\langle A,B\rangle$. One can show that $K$ is dense in $L$ using local uniform continuity of polynomials.

So, let us call an ordered field complete when it satisfies either condition. By Zorn’s lemma, every $K$ has a maximal ordered extension $\hat K$ in which it is dense. Then $\hat K$ is complete. As above, every element of $\hat K$ is uniquely determined by a good cut on $K$ (by density), and conversely every such cut is filled in $\hat K$ (by completeness), hence $\hat K$ can be identified with the set of all good cuts on $K$. One can easily check that it satisfies the appropriate universal conditions (e.g., if $K$ is dense in $L$, the mapping sending each element of $L$ to the cut on $K$ it determines is the unique ordered $K$-embedding of $L$ in $\hat K$), which also implies that $\hat K$ is unique up to isomorphism.

EDIT: As for references, the construction appears to be due to Dana Scott [On completing ordered fields, in: *Applications of Model Theory to Algebra, Analysis, and Probability*, New York, 1969, pp. 274–278], but unfortunately I don’t have access to this book.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've continued to find early precedents for this type of "proper cut" construction: it may go back at least to Veronese in the 19th century!

Answer (score 0):

The universal property of the completion of an ordered field as stated in Cohn's book (I mean, P.M. Cohn, Basic Algebra, Theorem 8.7.1) is true if we replace the assumption "each ***dense*** order embedding $f:K \rightarrow L$" instead of "each order embedding $f:K \rightarrow L$".